# Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, repository, spring-repositories

> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED

Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.example.newsapplication:egUsePieRotation:.
> Required by:
> project :app

Possible solution:

- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

Comment: Getting the same issue.. Have you found any solution for that??

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Anyone having solution?

Answer (score -1):

**I finally solved it**

**pluginManagent** section in **settings.gradle** should look like this:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```